# Group Policy Preference IE10

Tags: group-policy

I am trying to apply a Group Policy Preference for IE10. There are a few settings I only want applied once. I configured this, but if I login to a system with multiple users on one system, the GPP does not get set for each user. Once of my questions is, if the GPP is limited to IE10 and IE10 is not on the system, will the GPP run anyway and not run again?

Here is how I set it up: User config/preferences/Internet Settings/ New Internet Explorer 10. I went through and disabled all the settings with F8. I then went through and enabled the settings I wanted with F6. I only did about 12 settings. Most were on Security tab in Internet and Trusted Sites Zone. I then set it to run is Users context and only run once.

I just tested this. Our systems have IE8 currently. When I install IE10, the settings are not set. It is like the GPP runs on the system when IE8 is installed, then will not run again when IE10 is installed and I need the settings to be set.

I tried setting an ITL - Item Level targeting, so the GPP would only apply if the version of IE was between 10-11. It did not work. The thing is, the GPP has both "run once" preference and some that are set to run every time. Can you have both in one GPP?

Comment: Depends how you've configured the policy and if you've set any filters.
What policy are you rolling out?

Comment: We need more details!  What settings are you trying to set?  The details matter.  Keep in mind that group policies are primarily about setting registry values on a system.

Comment: This has been updated. @Aceth

Comment: Updated @Zoredache